# Show Hide form elements based on select Flask

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have developed a flask webform for my web project. I need to remove or Deactivate one file upload element base on User selection in select element.

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email')
    fileBase = FileField('Base OBS file:')
    fileObsRover= FileField('Rover OBS file:')
    fileNavRover= FileField('Rover NAV file:')
    password = TextField('Name')
    textarea = IntegerField('Elevation mask angle')
    #radios = RadioField('Frequecies', default='option1', choices=[('option1', 'L1'), ('option2', 'L2'), ('option3', 'L1 and L2')])
    selects = SelectField('Positioning mode', choices=[('0', 'Single Point Positioning'), ('1', 'DGPS/DGNSS'), ('2', 'Kinematic'), ('3', 'Static Positioning')])
```

I want to delete fileBase file field if user selected Positioning mode as Single Point Positioning before rendering the template.

I have read some articles about [Removing fields per instance](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.3/specific_problems.html#removing-fields-per-instance). But I'm having trouble implementing the same code for my form. Any suggestions are really appreciated.

I have tried using following code

```
def edit_issue():
    if Myform.selects.data == 'Single Point Positioning':
        del MyForm.fileBase
```

But the template wont delete when single point positioning selected

Answer (score 1):

[Removing Fields Per-instance](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.3/specific_problems.html#removing-fields-per-instance) is used before a form is rendered and sent to the browser. It looks like that you want to remove the field after it has been sent to the browser and a user has selected a particular option, in which case you will need to use Javascript in the browser to manipulate the form.

An alternative without resorting to Javascript would be to split your form processing into a two step process.

Define three forms as follows:

```
class PositioningModeForm(FlaskForm):
    selects = SelectField('Positioning mode', choices=[('0', 'Single Point Positioning'), ('1', 'DGPS/DGNSS'), ('2', 'Kinematic'), ('3', 'Static Positioning')])

class SinglePointPositioningForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email')
    fileObsRover= FileField('Rover OBS file:')
    fileNavRover= FileField('Rover NAV file:')
    password = TextField('Name')
    textarea = IntegerField('Elevation mask angle')

class OtherPointPositioningForm(SinglePointPositioningForm):
    selected_id = HiddenField()
    fileBase = FileField('Base OBS file:')
```

Note that `OtherPointPositioningForm` inherits from `SinglePointPositioningForm` so it has all the required input fields.  `OtherPointPositioningForm` also has a hidden field to store the selected positioning mode. You don't need this field in the `SinglePointPositioningForm` as you clearly know the positioning mode.

Step 1.

Send a PositioningModeForm to the browser asking the user what Positioning Mode they want to work on

Step 2

Process the form and internally redirect to either one of two routes depending on the selected Positioning Mode. One route renders a `SinglePointPositioningForm` whilst the other renders a `OtherPointPositioningForm`

Comment: Your suggestion looks promising for my task. So base on your update I have to create 3 individual web pages to handle 3 forms. First page should have a select element with a submit button. Then base on the input I have to redirect to either pages

Comment: @Richiedlon I've added a HiddenField to `OtherPointPositioningForm` so you can carry along the selected positioning mode.